# jQuery JSON parse via $.each - Cannot get length of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to parse a JSON response from a PHP call.

The returned data is in JSON format, as below:

```
{"success":true,
 "venues":
      [
          {"id":237,"title":"Country House Hotel and Restaurant","thumb_image":"thumb_combe-house-buttercups_3617067271.jpg","description":"","subType":1},
          {"id":579,"title":"Abode Exeter","thumb_image":"wvs.jpg","description":"","subType":0},
          {"id":484,"title":"Anran Luxury Boutique","thumb_image":"wvs.jpg","description":"","subType":0}
      ]
}
```

However, when I try to use the `$.each` function to loop over it, it is returning an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

A snippet of the code I am using to perform the $.each loop is below.

```
$.each(data.venues, function() {
    $.each(this, function(k, v) {
        alert(k + ' ' + v);
    });
});
```

Comment: did you `$.parseJSON()` the data?

Comment: You cannot use `$.each` on plain objects, such as on nested objects in `data.venues`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it works as expected, if you parseJSON the data.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

var data = $.parseJSON('{"success":true,"venues":[{"id":237,"title":"Country House Hotel and Restaurant","thumb_image":"thumb_combe-house-buttercups_3617067271.jpg","description":"","subType":1},{"id":579,"title":"Abode Exeter","thumb_image":"wvs.jpg","description":"","subType":0},{"id":484,"title":"Anran Luxury Boutique","thumb_image":"wvs.jpg","description":"","subType":0}]}');

$.each(data.venues, function() {
                $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                    alert(k + ' ' + v);
                });
            });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Demo: http://pascha.org/test/4.php

Comment: Something as simple as that! You rock! Works perfect once parseJSON is used. Could you explain why this is required, or point to some information on it?

Comment: Since JSON is just a String, Javascript first needs to create a js object of it, before you can use it. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/